# Why does the popup for b2c_1_edit_profile disappear?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I have b2c_1_susi working. I am able to login. I'm using example code. However edit profile user flow is not working. I have the user flow created in the same fashion as susi. If I use redirect my app navigates back to home page. If I use popup, the popup comes up but then disappears. This is what I am getting in the console log. [image: Console Log]

Comment: Look in the network trace, usually the error is appended to the reply url. Or look in the Application storage in Chrome dev tools, the MSAL object can contain the error in local storage.

Answer (score 0):

Strangely, I ended up deleting and recreating the registration and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add user attributes to your edit profile. You may already have user attributes on your sign up sign in profile but they do not get transferred over to the edit profile automatically